# Plotting SVG D3.js to ArcGIS map, need to stick with maps coordinate

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have some problem with sticking draggable SVG to ArcGIS map, using D3.js. Let's assume that I had latitude:-34.42507,longitude: 150.89315 to place some point that the SVG would be stick.

Here the point of code:

```
var newg = svg.append("g")
      .data([{x: width / 2, y: height / 2}]);

var dragline = newg.append("line")
                   .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.x + (width - 20); })
                   .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.y + (height - 20); })
                   .attr("x2", 700)
                   .attr("y2", 465)
                   .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                   .attr("stroke", "gray")
                   .attr("width",width)
                   .attr("height",height)
                   .attr("cursor", "move")
                   .call(drag);
```

When I drag the map, the SVG is stay on the screen, exactly with screen coodinates. What I want is the line is sticked with the map coordinates.

[image: moveable SVG]

What I supposed to do to insert coordinates and make them stick with maps? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are you adding the SVG to the map? Do you have a complete sample?